How does Sonoma work on a 2018 Macbook Pro?
I just got a 15in 2018 MacBook Pro.
Should I update to Sonoma or leave it as Monterey
My specs if you’d need them to answer the question are 32GB of DDr4 ram
2.9 GHZ 6core i9

Generally, you should update to the latest available OS.

Monterey is about to lose security support, so you should put Ventura on it, at least.

With those specs it will run well (depending on what apps you use).

It's inevitable that the newest OSes will take advantage of improvements in the latest hardware, and therefore older models will have to work harder.
However, it's also true that if the "user experience" wasn't good enough on a particular Mac, Apple would exclude that Mac from the list of supported devices.
Any supported Mac with an SSD and plenty of cores will work fine.

If you have a backup, you can always erase everything and reinstall, no?
I strongly update to get the security fixes as that's most important to me. I also have good experience with erase and reloading old OS, but we can't really know what apps you use, how technical you are and many other considerations, so in absence of your specifics, I recommend you follow Apple's advice which is to upgrade when they are available.
